# How can I plot various points on a world map and compare distances?

Tags: plotting, map, distance

How can I plot various points on a world map and compare distances?
For example, the distance between Jerusalem and Westford, MA compared to the distance between Westford, MA and Recife, Brasil? Then for a triangulation of the three points and measure the difference of distance between the three points?

Answer (score 3):

#### Entering Cities as Entities

For the cities, the following can be used

```
wes = Entity["City", {"Westford", "Massachusetts", "UnitedStates"}]
jer = Entity["City", {"Jerusalem", "Jerusalem", "Israel"}]
rec = Entity["City", {"Recife", "Pernambuco", "Brazil"}]
```

These input forms can be discovered by evaluating, for example, `InputForm @ Ctrl= Recife`, where `Ctrl=` means the control key + equal sign.

#### Plotting with GeoMarkers

Use `GeoMarkers` for plotting the city locations.  Use `GeoPath` for the paths.  See the documentation for the various path options.

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoMarker /@ {wes, jer, rec},
  GeoPath /@ Subsets[{rec, jer, wes}, 2]}]
```

[image]

Check the documentation on `GeoGraphics` and `GeoRange` for how to zoom out.

#### Distance

Use `GeoDistance` for the distance between the cities.

```
GeoDistance[wes, jer]   (*  Quantity[5526.35, "Miles"]  *)
```

Comment: +1 To include tooltips: `GeoGraphics[{Tooltip[GeoMarker[#], #] & /@ {wes, jer, rec}, Tooltip[GeoPath@#, GeoDistance @@ #] & /@ Subsets[{rec, jer, wes}, 2]}] // Quiet`

Comment: Thanks for the responses, LouisB and Bob Hanlon.